# Default wipe for some wipes using jQuery touchwipe

Tags: jquery, iphone, android, touch, touch-event

I'm using this wonderful plugin to capture wipe events on mobile devices: http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library

I'm using the code in the source of that page to get my image gallery cycling as it should be. However, my image gallery is the full width of the screen. Unfortunately, touchwipe seems to be preventing the default up and down wipes from scrolling up and down the page. Is there a way to make it use the default behaviour, except when other behaviour is specified?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imagegallery').cycle({
        timeout: 0,
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#prev' 
    });

    $("#imagegallery").touchwipe({
        wipeLeft: function() {
            $("#imagegallery").cycle("next");
        },
        wipeRight: function() {
            $("#imagegallery").cycle("prev");
        }
    });
});
```

I'm also open to other alternatives to achieving this same effect (other plugins, other methods). Thanks!

Comment: Looking at touchWipe's code, I see there's an option for `{preventDefaultEvents:true}`. However, I only want to prevent the default using the wipeLeft and wipeRight, and not for wipeUp and wipeDown. Maybe someone more capable could suggest how to modify the plugin to have multiple options of `{preventDefaultUp:false,preventDefaultLeft:true,etc.}`

Comment: This may help a little: Change the plugin options to `preventDefaultEvents: [true,true,true,true]` (top,right,b,l) and remove the line for prevent default. Then, add in the line `if(config.preventDefaultEvents[3]) {e.preventDefault();}` just above `config.wipeLeft();` and similarly for the different wipeDirs. This doesn't actually work, but it may help towards a solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just looking at your code, you only used it with the cycle plugin, right? Just wondering if anyone's been able to use the plugin to swipe an entire page content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a temporary answer that partially works, found here: http://plugins.jquery.com/content/vertical-scroll

It would be good to get a better answer though.

Comment: that just states the problem? did you fix it? could you post the vertical scroll code?

Answer (score 12):

With this small patch to the jquery.touchwipe library:

```
if(Math.abs(dx) >= config.min_move_x) {
     cancelTouch();
     if(dx > 0) {
-        config.wipeLeft();
+        config.wipeLeft(e);
     }
     else {
-        config.wipeRight();
+        config.wipeRight(e);
     }
  }
  else if(Math.abs(dy) >= config.min_move_y) {
     cancelTouch();
     if(dy > 0) {
-        config.wipeDown();
+        config.wipeDown(e);
     }
     else {
-        config.wipeUp();
+        config.wipeUp(e);
     }
  }
```

you can then change your code to selectively call e.preventDefault():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imagegallery').cycle({
        timeout: 0,
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#prev' 
    });

    $("#imagegallery").touchwipe({
        wipeLeft: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#imagegallery").cycle("next");
        },
        wipeRight: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#imagegallery").cycle("prev");
        },
        preventDefaultEvents: false
    });
});
```

(I've submitted the patch to the plugin author.)